# How to start another activity automatically?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activity (contentActivity) that when started need to call a second activity (newActivity) this second activity is only to inform the new ones of the app using a webview, after displaying the second activity the user can close the second activity and navigate normally through the activity (contentActivity).

I want to repeat this action whenever the user opens the activity (contentActivity). But after the activity (newActivity) is closed and the user returns to activity (contentActivity) does not repeat the action so the user does not get stuck in a loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO Eduardo; unfortunately, you may have to provide a concrete question with this. StackOverflow is not a place where people will write code for you, rather when you try something and it doesn't work the way it should, you share some pieces and we, the community, try to help you. But Android is not written in English, instead we use Java or Kotlin, so why don't you tell us what you tried? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started, you'd put the `startActivity()` code [seen here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) in `onCreate()` of the first activity.

When the user closes your activity number 2, you will write a boolean in the [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

And in the first activity, before calling `startActivity(...)` your're going to retrieve the boolean, if it's true, that means the user has already seen the other activity and you will skip calling start.

PSEUDO-CODE:

```
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate() 
  ...


  if (!sharedPref.get("USER_SAW_THE_OTHER_ACTIVITY")) { 
        startActivity(new Intent(...));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello friend, thank you for your response, it was a great help, although it seems easy now, I was lost, I am still inexperienced, and I apologize for the absence of code in the question, as mentioned in your other comment.

I believe that I communicated in the wrong way, because my intention was not that someone did the work for me, only sought the apredizado of how to carry out this action.

I spent a few hours searching and I did not find the correct way to do it, here in stackoverflow there are similar questions, but the answers point to a different path that did not work for my goal.

Comment: Because of this I decided to ask here explaining exactly the result that I wanted to achieve. I did not post the codes because I thought they were not necessary for the question, since they would only be codes of simple activities (functional), but that would not have codes of this action (even if broken).

Next time I'll post some code, thanks again.

Comment: No worries, Eduardo, I hope I didn't sound like I was chastising you or similar; my intention was to _educate_ you (no pun intended here) on how SO works. I'm not a moderator but I know users will immediately jump and tell you to include code, etc. In any case, you got the idea now and I hope it works for you. Perhaps, there are better ways to do what you're trying to do, but we don't know your use-case exactly as you do, and hence why we try to provide solutions to the problem at hand and not re-architect your entire idea :) Good luck and post any new question you have!